# How to use double line in LyX tables

Tags: tables, lyx, rules

I want to have double lines in the top row in my tables in lyx. I searched through the site but could not find how to do this.

Comment: There are several possible solutions. Could we have a minimal code?

Comment: I do not think LyX support for tables is intuitive in many cases. And I say this as one of the authors of the tabular code in LyX. I would like to redesign the code *someday*. I would appreciate it if you made a feature request for double lines in LyX at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Answer (score 3):

Due to the nature of the setup in LyX, you could insert a ERT with `\hline` in the first cell of the table:

[image]

Nothing should be placed before it, but you can put content after it. The output is fairly horrible though:

[image]

It is advisable to use the "Formal" table border setting instead (Edit > Table Settings... > Borders > Style > Formal), since it uses [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) in the presentation. This package uses `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` to emphasize the top/bottom of the table, setting it with a thicker rule.

Answer (score 0):

To get a double border for both top and bottom, we can use the "Formal" table border setting as mentioned by Werner, then add the following in the preamble to convert the top and bottom borders to double `\hline`:

```
\renewcommand\toprule{\hline\hline}
\renewcommand\bottomrule{\hline\hline}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the package hhline in the document preamble with `\usepackage{hhline}`, remove the bottom border in the first row and insert an ERT with `\hhline{|=|=|=|=|=|}` in the first cell of the second row (where the vertical bars `|=|...|` reflect your table structure).

[image: LyX screen capture]

The result looks correct:

[image: LyX table output]